# Azure ApplicationInsights Application Map doesn't show PostgreSql dependency by default

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-application-insights

In the Application Map feature of Azure ApplicationInsights, it seems that the PostgreSql db dependency is not shown by default, whereas Azure storage queues, blobs are shown, and so are other http dependencies. This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map) by Microsoft doesn't explain why either.

Does anyone know why and when this feature will be available?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's bc for .Net, PostgreSql is not an auto-collected dependency. You will have to manually wire it up, according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/auto-collect-dependencies).